# SQL Server : How to track changes value in a column and send notification email for only changed values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below that contains dealer codes and status. Every night between 1 and 6am  the status column may change for each dealer code. For example today the status of `00141.00062` is `operational`, but tomorrow it will be `deactivated` if the store was closed.

Briefly,I would like to track the changes using by stored procedures and send a notification email to me just for the updated values.

Lastly, I do not prefer to create a trigger cause of according to my previous experience it will be affect my main app. Therefore, I will be aprreciate if you can explain how I can do it via stored procedures.

```
 DEALER_CODE    STATUS
 ----------------------------
 00141.00062    OPERASYONEL
 01033.00061    DEACTIVE
 00070.00002    DEACTIVE
 00524.00002    DEACTIVE
 00387.00020    DEACTIVE
 00543.00001    DEACTIVE
 00310.00061    DEACTIVE
 00247.00062    OPERATIONAL
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL itself has no e-mail functionality.)

Comment: Its possible with creating profile in sql

Comment: Standart edition.. Actually I can handle the emai issue and I wrote a code.. Just I need to know what is the best way to track these changes

Comment: Create trigger rather then using mail service

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: thanks but I need a query to track this changes via trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `UPDATE` statement affects multiple rows at once, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but with multiple rows in the `Deleted` (old values before `UPDATE`) and `Inserted` (new values after `UPDATE`) pseudo tables. Therefore, it's the easiest to just compare those pseudo tables to figure out which rows have changed.

Also: I would ***strongly*** recommend to **NOT** send the e-mail directly from the trigger, since the trigger executes in the context of the `UPDATE` statement that caused it to fire and thus any delay in sending the e-mail just slows down your main app.

Instead, just add a row into a table, and then periodically (once every night, once every 4 hours or whatever suits your needs) have a separate process grab the new rows from that table and put those into an e-mail.

So the trigger should look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateStatus
ON dbo.YourTableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- insert a row into a "changed" table that will then be 
   -- used to asynchronously send out e-mails
   INSERT INTO dbo.ChangedDealerStatuses (DealerCode, OldStatus, NewStatus)
       SELECT
           old.Dealer_Code, old.Status, new.Status
       FROM 
           Deleted old
       INNER JOIN
           Inserted new ON old.Dealer_Code = new.Dealer_Code
       WHERE
           old.Status <> new.Status

END
```

Comment: Actually it is hard to insert rows because the table created by via different web-service. Thus, after this trigger I need to create a new a query just send to the changed dealer code right ? I will be glad also if you can share the query how I am gonna do that ?

Comment: Is it possible to make this via stored procedure ? As I guess I need to get a copy of this table periodically and call it old table and then 1 days later create an sp which will work at morning to check the changed values.Does it works?

Comment: @SemihUral: yes, of course - you could write a stored procedure that **(1)** checks the intermediate table for new entries, and **(2)** sends out e-mails as needed - and then you can schedule this stored procedure to be run as needed - once every hour, every day - whatever makes sense in your situation

Comment: Appreciate for your support but I will be glad if you can share example queries to catch the new entries.. I mean first of all I am create a new table that called dealer_detailed_old.Everynight I try to drop and create this table and insert essential data to this table from original table(1). What is the optimum query that I can track the changes and new inserted dealer code without trigger ?

Comment: @SemihUral: I can give you ideas (did that) and inputs, thoughts and my experience from 30+ years in the industry - but I ***cannot*** write the whole code for you. If you can't put together these things yourself, then you need to hire a freelancer who can

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `after update` trigger for this purpose. This is sample code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGERNAME -- NAME OF TRIGGER
ON TABLENAME -- NAME OF YOUR TABLE
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   IF UPDATE([STATUS])
   BEGIN
        PRINT 'STATUS COLUMN IS UPDATED'
        ---------------------TODO------------           
        -- INSERT INTO TABLE OR SEND EMAIL-------
   END
END
```

Note: please note that if update statement will be executed if update operation on column status. It never check if you have updated with same value.